# Gauss theorem sphere in first octant

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

> Given the portion of the sphere $S$ which is in the first octant ' $S:$ $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ ; $ x,y,z$ $\geq0$ , let $n$ be the unit normal vector (outwards) to $S$ . also given the vector field $F=(z,-y,x)$ . Find the flux of $F$ on $S$

We have the unit sphere $X^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the field $F=(z,-y,x)$ so $div=-1$ but our sphere is not closed , what I did was try to close it with the plane $z=0$ and then we can use gauss theorem

$\iint_S F \cdot n ds+\iint_P(z,-y,x) \cdot (0,0,-1)ds=\iiint_V -1 dV$

the triple integram is the sphere volume so I got $\frac{-4\pi}{3}$ but when I try to calculate $\iint_P(z,-y,x) \cdot (0,0,-1)ds$ I keep getting $-$ because $\iint_P -xds$ and since $z=0$ we get $x^2+y^2=1$ so the integral will be with $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and since I moved to polar coordiantes $J=r$ and $x=rcos\theta$ but this way the integral will be $0$ and the final answer in the book is $ \frac{4-\pi}{6}$

The way it was solved in the book was by solving a normal surface integral but I want to try in gauss theorem since it is the way I would think of.
I believe it should look like this [image]

Thanks for any tips and help!

Comment: I don't quite understand how $z=0$ closes the surface. Shouldn't it be three planes $x=0, y=0, z=0$?

Comment: @Trebor you are right.. let me try this again thank you (will update soon)

Comment: Yes close the surface with $3$ quarter disks in planes $x = 0, y = 0, z = 0$

Comment: @MathLover I keep getting zero in all of the integrals.. I dont know what am I doing wrong , $\iint_{p1} F(0,0,-1)ds$ + $\iint_{P2} F \cdot (0,-1,0)ds$ +$\iint_{P3} F(-1,0,0)ds$  I always get zero in each of them when I move to polar coordinates /$x=rcos\theta$ $y=rsin\theta$ and $z$ I tried as a normal surface integral so it was $z=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and then $ds=\sqrt{z^2_x+z^2_y+1}$

Comment: @Adamrk ok posting an answer in sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the surface with quarter disks in planes $x = 0, y = 0, z = 0$ and then apply Divergence theorem.

$\nabla \cdot \vec F = - 1$. The volume of the unit sphere in first octant is $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$.

So the net outward flux through the closed surface is $ - \dfrac{\pi}{6}$.

Now surface integral over quarter disk in $y = 0$ plane is zero as $\vec F = (z, 0, x)$ and $\hat n = (0, -1, 0)$. So $\vec F \cdot \hat n = 0$

Surface integral over quarter disk in $z = 0$ plane:

$\vec F = (0, -y, x)$ and $\hat n = (0, 0, -1)$.

Parametrize the disk as,

$(r \cos t, r \sin t, 0), \ \ 0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

So integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 (- r \cos t) r \ dr \ dt = - \dfrac{1}{3}$

You can see why it would be the same for the disk in plane $x = 0$.

So subtracting flux through disks, we get the flux through the spherical surface as,

$\dfrac{2}{3} - \dfrac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: thank you so much.. I honestly appreciate all your wonderful help . I know i ask a lot but just in general when $x=0$ and I need to integrate over $z$  is it the right thing to take $z=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and then do with $ds$ what I said in the previous comment? or is there a better way ? because I can't seem to get through with this.. and $0 \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ is because we are only on the positive sides of the axis? sorry again and thank you!!

Comment: when $x=0, \vec F \cdot \hat n = (z, -y, 0) \cdot (-1, 0, 0) = - z$ so yes it is $\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} - z \ dz \ dy $ which is a simple integral as you get $ - z^2/2$ after inner integral.

Comment: here is my problem , I kept going till $r=1$ thank you so much !

Comment: Please note we cannot put integrand $z$ as $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ as that is true only at the boundary of the disk and not in the entire disk.

Comment: @Adamrk and don't hesitate to ask questions. There are many who ask more than you and I never have a problem with that :)

Comment: thank you so much honestly you helped me a lot in this course!